# Anthology book with a short sci-fi story about a young man in school who has to write a report on Moby-Dick

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I’m looking for either the book or the title and author of this short story that I am trying to find. I read this book in high school, around 2003-2008, and recall it being a small hardcover book with either an orange or yellow cover.

It’s about a young man in school who has to write a report on *Moby-Dick*, but doesn’t understand why. He goes home to where he lives with his brother, and after making himself a sandwich, he digs around in his brother's room, grabs his holo pad, and looks at a holographic image of a man and women nude together. His brother walks in and he drops a slice of tomato from his sandwich onto the holo pad.

A fight happens and he’s crying on his brother's bed, as apparently his brother spanked him. The story ends with him watching his brother getting dressed and making a comparison between his brother and the whale in *Moby-Dick*.

Comment: What makes this a "scifi" story? By the way, wtr is a "halo pad"?

Comment: It was in a book of Science fiction stories. And the author described it as a flat pad that projects a holographic image on the pad.

Answer (score 11):

Could the short story be [Moby James by Patricia A. McKillip](https://readmeastoryink.com/stories/moby-james/), featuring in the anthology [2041: Twelve Short Stories About the Future](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122071.2041)?

Apparently, the summary of the story is:

> Rob struggles to understand Moby Dick and, at the same time why his older brother has turned on him. In the end, Ahab helps him understand his brother and bridge the gap between them.

Found with a Google search for short sci fi story about report on "Moby-Dick" "holo" which led to [this Google Books result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-2qNAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=short%20sci%20fi%20story%20about%20report%20on%20%22Moby-Dick%22%20%22holo%22&source=bl&ots=pW5Cp7x5Gh&sig=ACfU3U2CH0M70sr6J_S9eFwxw6an5F-Mqg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZjqnmt-f8AhXPWMAKHfLQBl0Q6AF6BAguEAM#v=onepage&q=short%20sci%20fi%20story%20about%20report%20on%20%22Moby-Dick%22%20%22holo%22&f=false).

Comment: Yes, this is it. I have a copy of the story in the [Holt Anthology of Science Fiction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?431075) and it matches the description perfectly.